# How to set caller id for Sinch App-To-Phone calling?

Tags: ios, voip, sinch

I have developed an app which does app to phone calling using Sinch framework. Calling works fine but the issue is I see a 4 digit number on receiver's phone but I would like receiver to see the registered number of caller. So I would like to set caller id or something like that for this. I tried to google it but I was not able to find any solution for that. Since app to app calling is having api to set caller id but  I'm looking for a solution to set caller id for Sinch app to phone calling.

would be nice to get some solution.

Else please suggest any other framework which does that.

Comment: That's a broad question .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use our verification product to enable this and we need to certify you to set caller id. Mail us at support@sinch.com to start that process.

Comment: Ok one more thing, 
can you tell me what are the parameters accepted in this method
[self.client.callClient callPhoneNumber:"+1462893" headers: headers]

here in headers

Comment: And yes, Can I set caller id of a verified number in header ?

Comment: This is turning in to a support ticket more. can you please ask "Ok one more thing, can you tell me what are the parameters accepted in this method [self.client.callClient callPhoneNumber:"+1462893" headers: headers] here in headers" as a new SO question or we take it in the support@sinch.com

Comment: @saint_n did you get an answer on how to pass a verified number in the headers?

Comment: @saint_n will you please tell me how you have solve this? how you set app to phone calling user id?

Comment: You will have to verify that phone with twilio first than you can use that as caller id