# How to set caller id for sinch javascript_api-to-PSTN calls?

Tags: javascript, sinch

I integrated Sinch's javascript api into our website and we are calling to PSTN numbers, now the reciever's screen show random number or no number at all, we would like to display a number that we rented from Sinch, how do we do that? I found a question but that scenario is different.
[Another SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33991959/how-to-set-caller-id-for-sinch-app-to-phone-calling)

Answer (score 1):

The caller id set using our callmethods/webhooks https://www.sinch.com/docs/voice/rest/#callbackapi and you set the cli in the response.

Comment: The method that you specified is for REST API, we are using Sinch's Javascript API/SDK, how do we handle callback api in this?